# Can't re-export strings to XLIFF from Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcode6.1, xliff

I started localizing my iPhone app from English to Portuguese, I added all necessary macros and changed the storyboards following the steps described on the official docs. When I finished I exported it to a Xliff xml file, as expected all english sentences were present on the resulting xml file. I continued the process by translating all sentences to portuguese and imported the xliff file into Xcode. I can now run the app and see all sentences in english or portuguese depending on my simulator configuration and everything works as expected.

Once I imported the XLIFF file there were several files created one of them being the Localizable.strings file which has the mapping between english and portuguese. I have continue developing my application and I'm now in the phase where I want to translate the new english strings I added to the project to portuguese. I tried the same process:

1. Export XLIFF with the current translations
2. Modify the XLIFF
3. Import it again back into Xcode

But for some reason that I'm not aware of I get a "Duplicate localized resource Localizable.strings found ". 
Question being: How can I export a XLIFF file with the current translations in a way that I can modify it and import it to xcode again ?

Thanks in advance
Ze

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I have the same problem, it's really annoying. Have you found a way to deal with this?

Comment: The XLIFF files are supposed to be exported and modified (translated), but only the target string should be modified, the best way is to use a tool for the translation. Did you try to import the file just exported without modifications to see if it works fine? if it does, next step should be to modify the translations using a tool like iXLIFF or any other XLIFF editor and avoid manually modifications at XML level.